# typescript how to get object key name from variable dynamic

Tags: typescript

in object array `fmuser`

```js
const fmuser = {
  fmcode: '000001',
  fmname: 'abc',
  as2021: 10,
  as2122: 20,
  as2223: 30,
  as2324: 40,
  as2425: 50,
};
```

I assign variable `yearId` from user select value is `2021,2122,2223,2324,2425`
if user selects `2324` ...how I get object key name is `as2324`

Thank you

Comment: Please, add some formatting, it's hard to read your question

Answer (score 0):

Use the square brackets syntax and template literals like:

```js
const fmuser = {
  fmcode: '000001',
  fmname: 'abc',
  as2021: 10,
  as2122: 20,
  as2223: 30,
  as2324: 40,
  as2425: 50,
};

const elFmuser = document.querySelector("#fmuser");
elFmuser.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const fmValue = fmuser[`as${elFmuser.value}`];
  console.log(fmValue); // Gives i.e: 30
});
```

```html
<select id="fmuser">
  <option selected disabled>— Select code —</option>
  <option>2021</option>
  <option>2122</option>
  <option>2223</option>
  <option>2324</option>
  <option>2425</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @KitidetSriboon you're welcome